# Exact solution to nonconvex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I would like to minimize $v+w+x+y+z$ subject to the following:

$$\frac{v+w}{x+y+z}=\frac{y}{z}=\frac{w}{x+y}$$

where $v,w,x,y,z\ge 1$

I tried entering this problem in WolframAlpha:

```
Minimize[{v + w + x + y + z, (v+w)/(x+y+z) == y/z &&  y/z== w/(x+y)&& v >= 1 && x >= 1 && y >= 1 && w >= 1 && z >= 1}, {v, w, x, y, z}]
```

It found a global min at $(v,w,x,y,z)=(1,\sqrt{2},1,1,\sqrt{2})$. What techniques might WolframAlpha be using to find this solution?

Comment: I do not know how it is implemented in WolframAlpha, but it is quite easy to find the exact solution analytically.

Comment: @A.Γ. What method would I use to find this solution analytically?

Comment: One may use the KKT necessary condition that gives a system of equations. I guess that Matematica being a symbolic package manipulates this system too.

Comment: @A.Γ.  I follow your logic, and I understand how this particular problem can be solved now. I would like the ability to solve hundreds of problems like this one relatively quickly. Some with more variables, more proportions, and more ratios in each proportion. So I was hoping for an solution that would be more easily generalizable. I guess I need to work on solving numerically instead. I haven't been able to recast this problem as a convex problem. If you have any suggestions for doing so, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Simplifying the constraints*. Set
  $$
  t=\frac{x+y+z}{v+w}=\frac{z}{y}=\frac{x+y}{w},
  $$
  then
  $$
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  x+y+z&=&t(v+w),\\
  z&=&ty,\\
  x+y&=&tw
  \end{array}\right.
  \quad\Rightarrow\quad y=v,
  $$
  and the problem becomes
  $$
  \min\, (1+t)(y+w)\quad\text{subject to }
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  1&\le&ty,\\
  1+y&\le&tw,\\
  1&\le&y,\\
  1&\le&w.
  \end{array}\right.\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  1-ty&\le&0,\\
  1+y-tw&\le&0,\\
  1-y&\le&0,\\
  1-w&\le&0.
  \end{array}\right.\tag{*}
  $$
- *Applying the [KKT necessary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)*.
  $$
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  1+t-\mu_1t+\mu_2-\mu_3&=&0,\\
  1+t-\mu_2t-\mu_4&=&0,\\
  y+w-\mu_1y-\mu_2w&=&0,\\
  \mu_1(1-ty)&=&0,\\
  \mu_2(1+y-tw)&=&0,\\
  \mu_3(1-y)&=&0,\\
  \mu_4(1-w)&=&0,\\
  \mu_k\ge 0\text{ and }(*)
  \end{array}
  \right.\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  1+(1-\mu_1)t+\mu_2-\mu_3&=&0,\quad(1)\\
  1+(1-\mu_2)t-\mu_4&=&0,\quad(2)\\
  (1-\mu_1)y+(1-\mu_2)w&=&0,\quad(3)\\
  \mu_1(1-ty)&=&0,\quad(4)\\
  \mu_2(1+y-tw)&=&0,\quad(5)\\
  \mu_3(1-y)&=&0,\quad(6)\\
  \mu_4(1-w)&=&0,\quad(7)\\
  \mu_k\ge 0\text{ and } (*)&&\ \ \ \ \quad(8)
  \end{array}
  \right.
  $$
- *Solution*. Equation (3) together with feasibility (*) leaves only 2 possibilites:
  Case 1: $1-\mu_1\ge 0$, $1-\mu_2\le 0$ or
  Case 2: $1-\mu_1\le 0$, $1-\mu_2\ge 0$.

Consider those cases.
*Case 1*. We have $\mu_2>0$ and from (1) $\mu_3>0$, hence, from (5) and (6) it follows that $$y=1,\quad tw=1+y=2.$$
 - Assume $\mu_1=0$. Then from (3) we have $(\mu_2-1)w=1$ and from (2)
   $\mu_4=1-t/w$.
If $\mu_4=0$ then $t=w=\sqrt{2}$ and the objective value is $\color{red}{(1+\sqrt{2})^2}$.
If $\mu_4>0$ then from (7) $w=1$, thus $t=2$ and the objective value is $\color{red}{6}$.
- Assume $\mu_1>0$. Then from (4) we get $1=ty=t$, thus $w=2$ and the objective value is $\color{red}{6}$.

*Case 2*. We have $\mu_1>0$ and from (2) $\mu_4>0$, hence, from (4) and (7) it follows that
$$
w=1,\quad ty=1.
$$
 - Assume $\mu_2=0$. Then from (3) we get $(\mu_1-1)y=1$ and from (1) $\mu_3=1-t/y$.
If $\mu_3=0$ then $t=y=1$ and the objective value is $\color{red}{4}$.
If $\mu_3>0$ then from (6) $y=1$, hence, $t=1$ and the objective value is $\color{red}{4}$.
 - Assume $\mu_2>0$. Then from (5) $1+y=tw=t$. It gives $1=ty=(1+y)y$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=\frac{1}{1+y}\le \frac12$. It is not possible as it contradicts $y\ge 1$.

Comparing the red objective values, it is clear that the smallest is for $y=1$, $t=w=\sqrt{2}$. Finally, $x=tw-y=1$, $z=ty=\sqrt{2}$ and $v=y=1$.